# Calculate time processing on different page php

Tags: php, timer

i've try this code on page one

```
$time_start = microtime(true);
$_SESSION['varname'] = $time_start;
```

and this code in page two

```
$time_start = $_SESSION['varname'];
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;
  echo 'Execution time : '.$time.' seconds';
```

but variable $time_start is unknown
how Calculate time processing on different page ?

Comment: You need to start session `session_start();`

Comment: i've add session_start(); before that script

Comment: I have try your code in my local and it's work fine.

Comment: i have undefined index varname in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\login_success.php on line 2.
and i have Execution time : 1469260664.3048 . what is that mean ?

Comment: It's because of you direct run your second page.

Comment: what should i do it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

**test1.php**

```
session_start();
$time_start = microtime(true);
$_SESSION['varname'] = $time_start;
```

**test2.php**

```
session_start();
$time_start = $_SESSION['varname'];
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;
echo 'Execution time : ' . $time . ' seconds';
```

**output:**
Execution time : 77.626733064651 seconds